# SimpleDateFormat gives ParseException

Tags: java

I'm fairly new here. I'm used to working with C# but I'm a newbie in java. 
I'm trying to get an hour String out of a jSpinner (Date model), but I keep getting errors. I've looked into some answers that are already given here... but it still doesn't work.

uurStr returns "Sat Jan 25 16:09:49 CET 2014", I'm trying to get "16:09" out of it. But no luck so far.... any ideas? 
The exception is thrown on the "uurDate = sdf.parse(uurStr);" part.

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String uurStr = String.valueOf(jSpinner1.getValue());
        Date uurDate = null; 
        try {
            uurDate = sdf.parse(uurStr);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmBackEnd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String uur = outputFmt.format(uurDate); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, uur);
```

Comment: Give us what uurStr holds normally.

Comment: I set the format as "HH:mm", but when I run it and I select (for example) 22:00, it returns "Sat Jan 25 22:00:00 CET 2014".

Comment: If you get the uurStr value as you say you do, it should parse just fine. Do you get parseexception OR the output in HH:mm seems to have some offset?

Comment: I get the exception... but I now tried to work around it and not use a jSpinner. So I got it working that way, altough I'm very intrested in what I did wrong. But thanks for the replies guys!

Comment: jesus.... do a println of uurStr and post it here.

Comment: `I'm used to working with C# but I'm a newbie in java` - don't you really feel like Marty McFly going back 200 years in the past?

Comment: I do... but it's schoolwork ;-).

Comment: @octagon: sorry for not really understanding what you mean... uurStr gets a String of the value of the jSpinner which is the full date format like "Sat Jan 26 00:00:00 CET 2014"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to correctly parse the weekday and timezone information, which both are language specific, it is necessary to set the locale as follows:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

If the locale is not set, then the default locale of the JRE is taken. This may be the OS default locale or a user specific locale or the locale may have been overridden by another Java class with `Locale.setDefault(Locale.XXXX)`. In any of these cases, this may be the correct locale or not.

That said, it is usually safer to set the timezone or you may get wrong time information if the timezone is not available in the string to be parsed:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

In your example the timezone is available and you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: I am glad it worked. Would you mind to rate my answer as accepted... Thanks.